Why does the application function in my AppDelegate receive empty urls on some models? 
This is my AppDelegate code. It's my first time developing a Mac application and I'm a bit unclear about it 
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    @StateObject var viewModel = GitHubCopilotViewModel()

    func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_: NSApplication) -> Bool { true }

    // Handle custom URL Scheme
    func application(_ application: NSApplication, open urls: [URL]) {
        Logger.gitHubCopilot.info("Application awakened by URL Scheme")
        Logger.gitHubCopilot.info("Application state: \(application.isActive)")
        Logger.gitHubCopilot.info("Bundle ID: \(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "unknown")")
        Logger.gitHubCopilot.info("Received SSO callback URL: \(urls)") // empty?? 
        guard let url = urls.first else { return }
        let scheme = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "SSO_URL_SCHEME") as? String ?? ""
        Logger.gitHubCopilot.info("Received callback URL Scheme: \(url.scheme ?? "")")
        Logger.gitHubCopilot.info("Target application callback URL Scheme: \(scheme)")
        if url.scheme == scheme {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                Logger.gitHubCopilot.info("Processing SSO callback")
                self?.viewModel.handleSsoCallback(
                    code: NSURLComponents(string: url.absoluteString)?.queryItems?.first(where: {
                        $0.name == "code"
                    })?.value ?? ""
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

I tried adding a lot of logs and found that only the M2 Pro chip MacBook has this issue

Note, @StateObject ... is only meaningful in a SwiftUI View (App, Scene), see: StateObject

Can you include log snippet of successful and failed sessions?

 if let userActivity = connectionOptions.userActivities.first {
            if userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb,
               let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL {
                handleIncomingURL(incomingURL)
            } else {
                print("URL Not Found")
            }
        }

you can add this code in willConnect To in  scene Delegate or any application function you are getting  UserActivity

The question is about macOS and AppKit, not iOS and UIKit.

you can get userActivity from application.UserActivity  in MacOs and you can use handle logic  @HangarRash

Yes but your answer mentions "scene delegate". Also, where does the question mention user activity?
